# How to create expandable view without using any library in android

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I'm creating an application in which I've an expandable view in my design.The thing is I can create it with Expandable listView or any other library. But I need to do that without listView or library. Is there any solution regarding this? The view I need to create is given below -[image: Exapndable View with sub menus]

So without using library and listView how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

as your requirement you need to do it without even list-view and i think you don't want adapter too so you can try this

> in your main activity
>   // inside Activity

```
 TextView txt_help_gest;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    txt_help_gest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_help_gest);
    // hide until its title is clicked
    txt_help_gest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}



>     /**
>     * onClick handler
>     */

public void toggle_contents(View v){
      txt_help_gest.setVisibility( txt_help_gest.isShown()
                          ? View.GONE
                          : View.VISIBLE );
}
```

> for some animations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fillAfter="true">

 <scale
 android:duration="200"
 android:fromXScale="1.0"
 android:fromYScale="0.0"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
 android:toXScale="1.0"
 android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

> java code

```
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

//...

/**
 *
 * @param ctx
 * @param v
 */
 public static void slide_down(Context ctx, View v){

  Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_down);
  if(a != null){
     a.reset();
     if(v != null){
      v.clearAnimation();
      v.startAnimation(a);
     }
  }
}
```

> /**
>       * on-click handler in main activity
>       */

```
public void toggle_contents(View v){

  if(txt_help_gest.isShown()){
    Fx.slide_up(this, txt_help_gest);
    txt_help_gest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
  else{
    txt_help_gest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Fx.slide_down(this, txt_help_gest);
  }
}
```